# creating and removing button dynamically. first time remove does well but second time can remove only ID without button space from layout

Tags: android

I want to create and remove button dynamically and I build up below code where, first time remove does well and when create a new button 
by pressing add button then I wanted to remove my button but it remove only button ID without its Button space and this ID can be used for second Time; please help me to understanding this problem.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button Add;
    Button Remove;
    public int Bindex=0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
Remove= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Remove);

Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
        Bindex++;
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ButtonLinearLayout);
        final Button Btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        Btn.setId(Bindex);
        Btn.setBackgroundColor(2);
        Btn.setTextSize(12);
        Btn.setWidth(5);
        layout.addView(Btn);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.setBackgroundColor(bn.getSolidColor());
                Btn.setText(String.valueOf(Btn.getId()));

            }
        });
}

Remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Button rmButton=(Button)findViewById(Bindex);
                    rmButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Bindex--;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problems solution.

Solution Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button Add;
    Button Remove;
    public int Bindex=0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
        Bindex++;
    GridLayout Gl= (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.ButtonGridLayout);
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        layout.setId(10000+Bindex);
        final Button Btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        Btn.setId(Bindex);
        Btn.setBackgroundColor(2);
        Btn.setTextSize(12);
        Btn.setWidth(5);
        layout.addView(Btn);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layout.setBackgroundColor(bn.getSolidColor());
                Btn.setText(String.valueOf(Btn.getId()));

            }
        });
}

Remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Button rmButton= (Button) findViewById(Bindex);
                    Input.setText(String.valueOf(rmButton.getId()));
                    numberOfTotalCloseTab=10000+Bindex;
                    rmButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    rmButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(numberOfTotalCloseTab);
                    GridLayout Gll= (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.ButtonGridLayout);
                    ll.removeView(rmButton);
                    Gll.removeView(ll);
                    Bindex--;
                }
}
```